# How can i get the right score?

Tags: c#, xna

I tried this to get the score in my game and I tried this:

```
foreach (stella stella in stelle)
            if (stella.rettangolo.Intersects(giocatore.rect))
            {

                score=score+10;

            }
```

It functions but not well because  if I stay a long time near the star the score continues to inrement even if it is not visible. how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question? In it's current form it is nearly impossible to see what is wrong and what exactly needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extra flag that tells you whether or not the star has been picked up. This must be a field in the `stella` class. Let's call it...

```
public bool captata; //I'll go with some Google translated Italian.
```

When the level starts, initialize it with the value `false`:

```
foreach (stella stella in stelle)
{
    stella.captata = false;
}
```

When the player intersects the star, you set the flag appropriately. At the same time, you only check for collision if the star hasn't been picked up yet.

```
foreach (stella stella in stelle)
   if ((!stella.captata) && (stella.rettangolo.Intersects(giocatore.rect)))
   {
       score=score+10;
       stella.captata = true;
   }
```

Another way would be to remove the star from the stars collection completely.

```
for (int i = stelle.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
   if (stelle[i].rettangolo.Intersects(giocatore.rect))
   {
       score = score + 10;
       stelle.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for italian translation. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your game logic so that you either remove the "star" from the "stars" collection once a player comes near it, or so that you mark it as touched by the player.

Depending on what the logic of the game is, you can also only have the player get points when they *start* touching the star, but not while they are *still* touching it. you can have a bool, `isTouchingStar` and set it to true if you detect the player touching it.

Comment: I tried it with a bool but it doesnt function anyway. The collision functions and the star disappears when I touch it.

Comment: That is exactly what the code should do, but I think the author misunderstood you.